# How to list all links in SE?

Tags: support

since FAA [no longer offers their publication via HTML pages and change all to PDF files](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/memo_at_pubs_html.pdf), many of links to FAA site have become a dead link.

How can I list all those links so I can find which link is bad and change them to a good one?

Comment: The short answer is [you get creative with the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/aviation/query/297700/posts-which-used-html-version-of-faa-p-cg-w-links) to search the database for posts containing part of the URL that usually indicates a link to something the FAA broke.